# How to place watermark on different parts of the image continously

Tags: java

File sourceImageFile = new File("C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\src\asian\paints\images\stations.png");
        BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageIO.read(sourceImageFile);

```
    File watermarkImageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MyProject\\src\\asian\\paints\\images\\error_indicate.png");
    BufferedImage watermarkImage = ImageIO.read(watermarkImageFile);

    File destImageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\watermarked.png");

    // initializes necessary graphic properties
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) sourceImage.getGraphics();
    AlphaComposite alphaChannel = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.3f);
    g2d.setComposite(alphaChannel);


    new Timer(0, new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            try {

       Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");  

    // calculates the coordinate where the image is painted
    int topLeftX = Integer.parseInt(jedis.get("x")) ;
    int topLeftY = Integer.parseInt(jedis.get("y")) ;

    System.out.println("x " + topLeftX);
    System.out.println("y " + topLeftY);

    // paints the image watermark
    g2d.drawImage(watermarkImage, topLeftX, topLeftY, null);

    ImageIO.write(sourceImage, "png", destImageFile);
    g2d.dispose();
```

//        System.out.println("The image watermark is added to the image.");

```
    ImageIcon iconLogo = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\watermarked.png");
      // In init() method write this code
     jLabel1.setIcon(iconLogo);


} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}

        }
    }).start();
```

The above program changes the watermark position only for the first time when the executed. It will not change its position after that.

Comment: It gives error java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\\Desktop\watermarked.png (Access is denied)

Comment: Access is controlled by the operating system not JVM. Change access rigths of the folder so that the java process can write to the folder or choose another folder with suitable access rigths. On Windows this might happen as well, if the file is used by another process (e.g. opened with another application). It is annoying that even in this case a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown but the error message is something like _in use by another process_. In that case close the other application.

Comment: File is given full access permission.